# SPARQL - Filter comment. label and abstract to english and keep integer as well as uri values

Tags: filter, sparql

I'm trying to get available information about certain resources from DBPedia.
However, I want to filter out the label, comment and abstract to be only in english.

My original query is:

```
SELECT ?property ?value (lang(?value ) as ?lang) { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/England> ?property ?value . }
```

To filter the english results I have modified it to:

```
SELECT ?property ?value (lang(?value ) as ?lang) { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/England> ?property ?value .  FILTER(LANG(?value) = "en") }
```

However, doing this I lose a lot of entries and information such as population, density, position, latitude, longitude  and many many more.

I was wondering, if there is a way to get all the available entries but filter the `abstract`, `label` and `comment` to be only in English.

I have tried to modify my Query to the following:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?property ?value (lang(?value ) as ?lang) { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/England> ?property ?value .   FILTER(LANG(?rdfs:label) = "en")}
```

Unfortunately, I did not get any results since the query is false.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51422162/

Comment: @StanislavKralin using the following has no results:

`PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?property ?value (lang(?value ) as ?lang) { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Germany> ?property ?value .  
FILTER(lang(rdfs:label) = "en") }`

Comment: UPDATE:
I worked on the query and writing like this:
`SELECT ?property ?value (lang(?value ) as ?lang) { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/England> ?property ?value . FILTER(LANG(?value) = "" || LANGMATCHES(LANG(?value), "en")) }`

Gives me almost desired results. Doing this query leads to losing all the uri links available. Is there a way to have the same results but include all the links as well ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have answered my own question after a thorough research.
You can use the `FILTER` function to get all the values with or without any `@en` or `language` part available. For this you can use the following part:

```
FILTER(LANG(?value) = "" || LANGMATCHES(LANG(?value), "en")
```

However, this leads to losing all the available `uri` and other `links`.
If one also wants to get all the links besides the *English filtered results*, one will also need a similar function to the `startsWith` function. Its equivalent in the SPARQL language is called `strstarts`.  I have added the following part to the `FILTER` in my query and I have gotten all originally needed results.

```
strstarts(str(?value), 'http'))
```

So this is the resulting query. Hint I have removed the PREFIXES since I do not need them in my query

```
 SELECT ?property ?value { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/England> ?property ?value .
      FILTER(LANG(?value) = "" || LANGMATCHES(LANG(?value), "en") || strstarts(str(?value), 'http'))}
```

Comment: I would suggest your answer is an improvement of the original answer. I would not give a negative point like you just because it is not the *most efficient query*. 
It should be clear that I'm not an expert with regards to SPARQL, otherwise I would not have asked the question in the first place. Nevertheless, thanks for your input.

Comment: it's more efficient to check for the entity type that doing string operations for sure, but ok I don't care. I also did **not** downvote your answer by the way, you should be careful with such an assumption as you can't see who did what on SO. Anyways, will remove my previous comment, your query is working, thus, who cares. Don't forget to accept your own answer to mark the question as resolved.